# How do I see from the Etherscan or Bscscan my current holdings of the pair in the liquidity pool?

Tags: etherscan, bsc, liquidity-provider, pancakeswap

After staking into the Pancake Swap liquidity pool - CAKE-BNB 0x0eD7e52944161450477ee417DE9Cd3a859b14fD0, the initial staking amount will change, how can I find out my current holdings of each coin the the pool via Bscscan? Can we query it from the Contract Tab - "Read contract" ?

We can see the smart contract's current holdings via Token Holdings but how do we see our current holdings ?

[image: Contract's current holdings]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can view them by adding your LP (liquidity provider) address in metamask.

Comment: ??? ip address in metamask?

Comment: LP address not ip address. The address of the pair created

Comment: Sorry I did read ip and not LP 